# Convert JInputStream to Base64

Tags: java, android, delphi, firemonkey

I convert a `JInputStream` to base64 with a `MemoryStream` as intermediary. I need to do that because `JInputStream` doesn't extend the base class `TStream`.

I deliberately simplified the code by removing the try/finally block.

```
JStream := TAndroidHelper.ContentResolver.openInputStream(StrToJURI(FSelector.Files[I]));
Buffer := TJavaArray<Byte>.Create(JStream.Available);
JStream.Read(Buffer);

MStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
MStream.Write(Buffer.Data^, Buffer.Length);
MStream.position := 0;

SStream := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.ASCII);
Soap.EncdDecd.EncodeStream(MStream, SStream);
Base64Stream := SStream.DataString;
Base64Stream := Base64Stream.Replace(#10, '');
Base64Stream := Base64Stream.Replace(#13, '');
```

Does a method exist to directly convert the data of my `JInputSream` to base64?

Comment: 1) There are a lot of base64 encoder/decoder available for Delphi. Google is your friend. With those encoders you could avoid so much data copy (stream->array->memoryStream->base64 stream. 2) I'm almost sure JStream has methods to read a block of bytes to avoid moving data to an array.

Comment: You can avoid one copy, at least, by using `TCustomMemoryStream` and pointing it at the array's existing memory. Also, base64 is trivial to implement manually, so you could avoid reading the entire stream into memory at one time, just read from it a few bytes at a time in a loop, encoding those bytes into characters with a few bit shifts

Comment: Also, Android has its [own Base64 encoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64), but it takes a `byte[]` array as input, not a `Stream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import for the Android Base64 class:

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNIBridge, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes;

type
  JBase64Class = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{DA78E162-4CB0-455B-ACC0-BEDDE5484C85}']
    function _GetCRLF: Integer; cdecl;
    function _GetDEFAULT: Integer; cdecl;
    function _GetNO_CLOSE: Integer; cdecl;
    function _GetNO_PADDING: Integer; cdecl;
    function _GetNO_WRAP: Integer; cdecl;
    function _GetURL_SAFE: Integer; cdecl;
    function decode(input: TJavaArray<Byte>; flags: Integer): TJavaArray<Byte>; cdecl; overload;
    function decode(input: TJavaArray<Byte>; offset: Integer; len: Integer; flags: Integer): TJavaArray<Byte>; cdecl; overload;
    function decode(str: JString; flags: Integer): TJavaArray<Byte>; cdecl; overload;
    function encode(input: TJavaArray<Byte>; flags: Integer): TJavaArray<Byte>; cdecl; overload;
    function encode(input: TJavaArray<Byte>; offset: Integer; len: Integer; flags: Integer): TJavaArray<Byte>; cdecl; overload;
    function encodeToString(input: TJavaArray<Byte>; flags: Integer): JString; cdecl; overload;
    function encodeToString(input: TJavaArray<Byte>; offset: Integer; len: Integer; flags: Integer): JString; cdecl; overload;
    property &DEFAULT: Integer read _GetDEFAULT;
    property CRLF: Integer read _GetCRLF;
    property NO_CLOSE: Integer read _GetNO_CLOSE;
    property NO_PADDING: Integer read _GetNO_PADDING;
    property NO_WRAP: Integer read _GetNO_WRAP;
    property URL_SAFE: Integer read _GetURL_SAFE;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/util/Base64')]
  JBase64 = interface(JObject)
    ['{AC976256-7237-4F07-87CD-B57F5F28BF6A}']
  end;
  TJBase64 = class(TJavaGenericImport<JBase64Class, JBase64>)
  end;
```

Function to encode the file-based URI into Base64:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Androidapi.Helpers, Androidapi.JNI.Net, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes;

function JURIToBase64(const AJURI: Jnet_Uri): string;
var
  LInput: JInputStream;
  LJavaBytes: TJavaArray<Byte>;
  LBytes: TBytes;
begin
  LInput := TAndroidHelper.Context.getContentResolver.openInputStream(AJURI);
  LJavaBytes := TJavaArray<Byte>.Create(LInput.available);
  try
    LInput.read(LJavaBytes, 0, LJavaBytes.Length);
    Result := JStringToString(TJBase64.JavaClass.encodeToString(LJavaBytes, TJBase64.JavaClass.NO_WRAP));
  finally
    LJavaBytes.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Example usage based on your requirements:

```
Base64Result := JURIToBase64(StrToJURI(FSelector.Files[I]));
```